# Word Document in Sharepoint - VSTO

Tags: sharepoint-2010, vsto, contenttype

Here is what I have done.

1. Created a document template [ word 2010 ]  in VS 2010.
2. Added few content controls to the document.
3. List item
4. On save event, calling DB [ using EF]
5. Publish to a network share [ Everyone has full control to this share ]
6. Created a content type and uploaded the template from the share.

I have given full trust to the share, the document library and the content type in using .net configuration tool. i also added these to the word trust center

I can get an error
Customization does not have permissions required to create an application domain. 
Customized functionality in this application will not work bcos the administrator has listed file://share/deploy/file.vsto as untrusted.

Where am i going wrong. Its been over a week now and its very frustrating.

Comment: A similar thread if it gives any pointers - [Problem after installing VSTO runtime 2010 and .Net framework 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6013363/problem-after-installing-vsto-runtime-2010-and-net-framework-4)

Answer (score 0):

U have to add certyficate to your template/form